# Playwright test fails when using waitForResponse

Tags: javascript, async-await, playwright

My playwright test never passes when I use the command "page.waitForResponse". Although the API call is performed and can be seen in the network tab of chrome. I set the jest timeout to 30000, but this does not seem to be the issue.

```
it("Test", async () => {
  await page.goto("http://localhost:8080/")
 await Promise.all([
  await page.waitForResponse("https://development/my/call", {
    timeout: 1000,
  }),
  page.click("css=body")
])
})
```

Network

```
url: https://development/my/call
Status: 200
Type: xhr
```

Error

```
Async callback was not invoked within the 30000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error
```

Comment: The golden rule for `Promise.all()`: virtually never should any of the array elements have `await` in front of them--you want to pass the promises, not their resolved values, into the `Promise.all` array. You want to await the result of all the promises, one time, which is the `await` in front of `Promise.all()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be in what you don't include in your question.

Typically, you have to start waiting for the response before the action that causes the call happens. Let's say that action is some click somewhere on the page, then you want to type:

```js
await Promise.all([
    page.waitForResponse("http://localhost:8060/my/call"),
    page.click('.someButton'),
]);
```

Try this, it might be what will solve your problem.

Comment: I put page.click("css=body"), but still it fails

Comment: Is your url string correct? Many times, it's enough to match only by an endpoint `page.waitForResponse('/my/call')`. It cal also be a regex, function. Try to play with this a bit.

Comment: it still fails, strange

Comment: Ok, I think you need to include a bit more info in the question. obviously there's some missing bit of info that's crucial in here. Post a screen of the call from the Network tab, more of your code (a few lines above and below of this waitForReponse() method call.

Comment: I see, but that's not what I posted, there's not `await Promise.all()` for example.

Comment: I added the Promis.all but it still dos not pass

Comment: Really, you need to exactly copy my code, you have await in front of `page.waitForResponse()` inside `Promise.all()`. That's not how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: I'll add another line to this in case somebody is struggling. In my case it was a missing `await` preceding a function helper that was failing in random places but at different times so it seemed as if it was the API call when in fact it was the helper function itself. Just a note: When in doubt => CHECK YOUR AWAITS.